# Selenium not able to find new window handle in IE MODE but working in normal mode ( internet explorer )

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to switch to a new window that will open when I login to the previous page. After clicking the login button a new tab will be open and gets closed immediately then a new window is open, this window handle is not recognized by the Selenium IE driver in **IE MODE** but I'm able to switch to this new window while automating in normal Internet Explorer browser. Selenium version is 4.3.0.0.

The code that I'd tried to switch to that new windows:

```
Thread.sleep(3000); // This delay is to avoid the new tab that gets closed immediately without this delay the driver is trying to switch to that new tab, after that any operation leads to throwing no browser exception. So this line is saving from the issue.
String desiredTitle = "";

while (!desiredTitle.contains("new window")) {
    for (String ewh: driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        desiredTitle = driver.switchTo().window(ewh).getTitle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're [known limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=java#known-limitations) in Selenium 4 for IE mode automation. One of the workarounds suggests waiting until the driver gets the handle. You can try the sample code provided in that doc.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer but that approach present in known limitations was already tried before but that didn't work, since it only catches the number of windows but that I don't need because I want to switch to the specific window having some title and also as I already mentioned in the question that after clicking the login button immediately a new tab gets opened and closed after that new window pops up, this window I need to switch but time taking by the new window is unpredictable. I hope you got my point. Cheers :)

Comment: Yeah, I get it. And I've tested my IE driver to fetch a handle/title of a newly created window using your code. Actually, it works in my case. You can check twice whether the "new window" is exactly (part of) your new window's title. BTW, I'm using IE driver 4.3.0.0, and it should work according to a [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG) saying that it "fixed Edge IE mode issue that sometimes cannot get the handle of a newly opened window". You can raise a question there informing the Team that this issue hasn't been fully solved. Regards.